# How to convert byte array to bitmap in xamarin.ios?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, bitmap, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to convert byte array to a bitmap in my xamarin.ios app but it's not working. I have tried using `Bitmap  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageArray, 0, imageArray.Length);` but with the error `CS0103: The name 'BitmapFactory' does not exist in the current context`.[image]

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: `BitmapFactory` is an Android API.  In iOS use `UIImage.LoadFromData()`